# convert json file to data frame in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am new to json file handling. I have a below json file

```
{"loanAccount":{"openAccount":[{"accountNumber":"986985874","accountOpenDate":"2020-02-045-11:00","accountCode":"NA","relationship":"Main account","loanTerm":"120"}]}}
```

I want to convert this into dataframe. I am using the below code :

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data1 = pd.read_json (r'./DLResponse1.json',lines=True)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1, orient='columns')
```

This is giving me the below output :

```
index   loanAccount
0       {'openAccount': [{'accountNumber': '986985874', 'accountOpenDate': '2020-02-045-11:00', 'accountCode': 'NA', 'relationship': 'Main account', 'loanTerm': '120'}]}}
```

However I want to extract in the below format :

```
loanAccount  openAccount  accountNumber  accountOpenDate    accountCode  relationship  loanTerm
                          986985874      2020-02-045-11:00   NA          Main account  120
```

Comment: there is a problem with your json file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use:

```
# s is your json, you can read from file
pd.DataFrame(s["loanAccount"]["openAccount"])
```

output:

[image]

if you want also to have the other json keys as columns you may use:

```
pd.DataFrame([{"loanAccount": '', "openAccount": '', **s["loanAccount"]["openAccount"][0]}])
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code but unfortunately I am not getting the expected output. Getting error `KeyError: 'openAccount'`. I first loaded my json file which I mentioned in my query and then I used your code.However I tried this `x =pd.DataFrame([{"loanAccount": '', **data1["loanAccount"][0]}])` but this also seems not working for me. I am new to json file handling so could not able to resolve this error.

Comment: maybe you have a diffrent json than the one from question ? can you check again ?

Comment: you should read the json like : with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

Comment: I used this command to read json file `data1 = pd.read_json (r'./DLResponse1.json',lines=True)` and `DLResponse1` file contains exactly what I have mentioned in my above json data.

Comment: `with open('data.json') as f: data = json.load(f)` with this reading method, it works for me.. thanks a lot